Getting issue implementing firebase cloud messaging
I am currently using firebase npm package and using it's getToken function from "firebase/messaging" for firebase push notifications service while correctly passing vapidKey as below
I have write code for taking notification permission as well which is working fine but code for generating token is
const fcmToken = await getToken(messaging, {
        vapidKey:
          "Passing valid vapid key",
      });
      localStorage.setItem("fcmToken", fcmToken);

I am passing valid messaging configuration as below
{
apiKey,
authDomain,
projectId,
storageBucket,
messagingSenderId,
appId,
measurementId
}

But it's still throwing error
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}

Can anybody please help
I validated the messagingConfig and vapidKey and matched with firebase documentation but everything seems right
